# Translation into the propositional logic

Tags: propositional-calculus, logic-translation

How could the following sentence be translated into the propositional logic?

```
Since I am here I talk to you.
```

Do I have to use implication like p -> q?

Comment: What you've highlighted is not, logically, a proposition.

Comment: sorry, i edited it

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it would then be $p\Rightarrow q$, where $p$ is “I am here”, and $q$ is “I talk to you.” In general, “Since $p$, $q$” translates to $p\Rightarrow q$.